# Cannot view close votes

Tags: support

According to the FAQ (click here: [View close votes privilege](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/view-close-votes)), I should be able to view close votes since I have the required 250 reputation points. But I cannot figure out how.

In fact, when I look under the main text of the questions asked by other people, the list of options provided to me reads:

> `link edit retag flag`

But the FAQ says it should instead be something like (see the picture within the linked page):

> `link edit close(1) flag`

I guess that the (1) stands for the number of close votes.

Can someone explain what's going on here, or what I am doing wrong? I feel like I am missing something straightforward.

*Edit.* Turns out I just had to read the FAQ more carefully. @J.M.'s answer points out that I can do this only after gathering 3000 points.

Comment: If it wasn't clear, the set of options I have mentioned is for other people's questions, not the ones I asked. I can see a `close` option in my questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That only works for *your* questions at your current rep level. You need to reach [3000 rep](https://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions) before you can see that for others' questions.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks. (All this after I was convinced I read the FAQ carefully enough :))